# Why Select2 element appear on outside of div while data is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using select2 element for choosing names.when i choose more than names the select2 box appear outside of the div.I need to the select2 box appear in the div only.

Html code:

```
    <div class="row well container col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <h4 style="color:teal;font-weight:bold;">
        <center> Sales Entry Form</center>
    </h4>
    <div >
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="sales_entry_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="sales_entry_retailer" type="hidden"  style="height: 33px;width: 100%;" placeholder="Select Retailer" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div >
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div  id="sales_entry_form_div">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="sales_entry_table" >
            <thead id="sales_entry_head"></thead>
            <tbody id="sales_entry_body"></tbody>
            <tfoot id="sales_entry_foot"></tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here i apply select2 box for hidden type.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you post jsfiddle  ?

Comment: I was solved this problem by removing { style="height: 33px;width: 100%;"} in input element. Thank you for your response @ Atul Nar